# Windows Update Failure 0x80240034

Tags: windows, wsus

Specific updates are failing to install. They sit at downloading and eventually fail with the error 0x80240034. I have done a wsusutil reset and tried to download the updates again with no success. I have installed other updates, deleted software distro folder and tried again. The VMs are pointing to the correct WSUS server.

I was able to download and update these manually but some VMs do not have that option as they are not connected to the internet and also do not communicate with the VMs in which I was able to manually update.

Some Failing updates are KB890830 Windows Malicious Software Tool, KB 2267602 Security Intelligence for Microsoft Defender Antivirus, KB5030333 SQL Server 2019 RTM Cumulative Update, KB5029377 Security Update for SQL Server 2019 RTM GDR. All failing updates event show as unable to find resource.

```
2023/11/27 16:19:39.4147967 4404 8064 DataStore * START * tbPerSessionData Dump

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4148187 4404 8064 DataStore [1] 4FED5ACF-C304-44B9-AE55-84EB7FFE1E27.200; SD: (null); NotPresent; Unlocked

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4148334 4404 8064 DataStore [2] 4AAF207E-4C20-40B1-A9A4-4599129527BD.200; SD: (null); NotPresent; Locked

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4148408 4404 8064 DataStore [3] 96FDE0BF-DBC9-44E8-8AA0-3CB0C29FA5CE.200; SD: (null); NotPresent; Unlocked

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4148479 4404 8064 DataStore [4] AFA2C546-7A4A-4479-8551-8264564FFFF1.200; SD: (null); NotPresent; Locked

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4148555 4404 8064 DataStore [5] C8D27018-8E1D-4AF4-AD67-EE76224214CF.200; SD: (null); NotPresent; Unlocked

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4148635 4404 8064 DataStore [6] E1DC98A4-FBBB-43D2-B235-D0881D0E86FD.200; SD: (null); NotPresent; Locked

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4148713 4404 8064 DataStore [7] A20338F8-9EB2-48F7-AAA0-D5B6984BD2CA.200; SD: (null); NotPresent; Locked

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4148788 4404 8064 DataStore [8] E99F6E29-371F-40EA-9CB5-27AE26A2B78D.200; SD: (null); NotPresent; Unlocked

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4148811 4404 8064 DataStore * END * tbPerSessionData Dump. 8 updates

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4148896 4404 8064 DataStore * START * tbUpdate Dump for 96FDE0BF-DBC9-44E8-8AA0-3CB0C29FA5CE

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4162215 4404 8064 DataStore [1] 96FDE0BF-DBC9-44E8-8AA0-3CB0C29FA5CE.200; SrvRef: 1

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4168172 4404 8064 DataStore * END * tbUpdate Dump. 1 updates

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4168257 4404 8064 DownloadManager FAILED [80246007] MapToLockedRevisionUpdate 96FDE0BF-DBC9-44E8-8AA0-3CB0C29FA5CE.200 (sessionData: (null)) failed

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4168292 4404 8064 DownloadManager FAILED [80246007] Method failed [CAgentDownloadManager::OpenUpdateInstallDirectory:18158]

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4168352 4404 8064 Agent FAILED [80246007] Method failed [CAgentUpdateManager::PrepareInstallData:11085]

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4168501 4404 8064 Agent FAILED [80246007] Method failed [CAgentUpdateManager::InstallUpdate:11739]

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4242288 4404 8064 Agent LogHistory called. idUpdate={A20338F8-9EB2-48F7-AAA0-D5B6984BD2CA}.200, resultMapped=80246007, resultUnMapped=80246007

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4293641 4404 8064 Agent Install updates CallerId = AWS EC2 PatchNow

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4332391 4404 8064 IdleTimer WU operation (CInstallCall::Init ID 40, operation # 429) stopped; does not use network; is not at background priority

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4337608 7628 6660 ComApi Install ClientId = AWS EC2 PatchNow

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4337649 7628 6660 ComApi Install call complete (succeeded = 0, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 2, cancelled = 0, unaccounted = 0

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4338103 7628 6660 ComApi Reboot required = False

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4338835 7628 6660 ComApi Exit code = 0x00000000; Call error code = 0x80240022

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4338892 7628 6660 ComApi * END * Install ClientId = AWS EC2 PatchNow

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4339277 4404 3644 Agent WU client calls back to install call {84775FF3-0020-4043-8786-3C946559A772} with code Call complete and error 0

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4375558 7628 5800 ComApi Install call complete (succeeded = 0, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 2, cancelled = 0, unaccounted = 0

2023/11/27 16:19:39.4375704 7628 5800 ComApi * END * All federated installs have completed. ClientId = AWS EC2 PatchNow (cV = AKTysvsOV0qoExsu.8.1)

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3181463 5424 512 ComApi * START * Federated Download ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator (cV = o3256S27+Uys6Pww.2.0)

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3249106 5424 3100 ComApi Federated Download: Starting download for 1 service(s) (cV = o3256S27+Uys6Pww.2.0)

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3250060 5424 3100 ComApi * START * Download ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3250083 5424 3100 ComApi Flags: 0X1900C; Download priority: 3; Network Cost Policy: 3

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3250097 5424 3100 ComApi Updates in request: 1

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3250208 5424 3100 ComApi ServiceID = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} Managed

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3336573 5424 3100 ComApi QUEUED Download ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3344215 4404 1292 Agent Effective power state: AC; IsOnAC: Yes.

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3344342 4404 1292 IdleTimer WU operation (DL.UpdateOrchestrator) started; operation # 450; does use network; is not at background priority

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3344466 4404 1292 Agent Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {34EFDE9E-A731-4078-B7EE-71B77C3722D7} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 450.

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3371094 4404 1292 DownloadManager * START * Begin Downloading Updates [CallerId = UpdateOrchestrator] [Call ID = {34EFDE9E-A731-4078-B7EE-71B77C3722D7}]

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3371169 4404 1292 DownloadManager Priority = 3, NetworkCostPolicy = 3, Interactive = 1, Download on Battery = 1, Bypass Regulation = 1, Owner is system = 1, Proxy session id = 4, ServiceId = 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7.

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3371187 4404 1292 DownloadManager Updates to download = 1

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3371221 4404 1292 Agent Title = Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.401.1202.0) - Current Channel (Broad)

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3371260 4404 1292 Agent UpdateId = A20338F8-9EB2-48F7-AAA0-D5B6984BD2CA.200

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3371271 4404 1292 Agent Bundles 5 updates:

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3371305 4404 1292 Agent E1DC98A4-FBBB-43D2-B235-D0881D0E86FD.200

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3371337 4404 1292 Agent 96FDE0BF-DBC9-44E8-8AA0-3CB0C29FA5CE.200

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3371369 4404 1292 Agent AFA2C546-7A4A-4479-8551-8264564FFFF1.200

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3371400 4404 1292 Agent C8D27018-8E1D-4AF4-AD67-EE76224214CF.200

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3371432 4404 1292 Agent E99F6E29-371F-40EA-9CB5-27AE26A2B78D.200

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3371810 4404 1292 DownloadManager No locked revisions found for update 96FDE0BF-DBC9-44E8-8AA0-3CB0C29FA5CE.200 (SessionData = (null)); locking the user-specified revision.

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3379506 4404 1292 DownloadManager No locked revisions found for update C8D27018-8E1D-4AF4-AD67-EE76224214CF.200 (SessionData = (null)); locking the user-specified revision.

2023/11/27 16:20:07.3388489 4404 1292 DownloadManager No locked revisions found for update E99F6E29-371F-40EA-9CB5-27AE26A2B78D.200 (SessionData = (null)); locking the user-specified revision.

2023/11/27 16:20:25.0562557 4404 1292 DownloadManager DO job initialized: JobId = {2C86DA36-F73C-4CEA-BE77-C4A714DF3F94}

2023/11/27 16:20:25.0579427 4404 1292 DownloadManager Downloading from http://10.17.x.x:8530/Content/52/EF223B4399D7457A43BC2C2DCE36D8D29B9FEA52.exe to C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\dc19fcd110c89a4788d27783d239dfdc\ef223b4399d7457a43bc2c2dce36d8d29b9fea52 (full file)

2023/11/27 16:20:25.0579556 4404 1292 DownloadManager Created download job 2C86DA36-F73C-4CEA-BE77-C4A714DF3F94; streaming data: No.

2023/11/27 16:20:25.0590676 4404 1292 DownloadManager New download job {2C86DA36-F73C-4CEA-BE77-C4A714DF3F94} for UpdateId 96FDE0BF-DBC9-44E8-8AA0-3CB0C29FA5CE.200

2023/11/27 16:20:25.0594344 4404 1292 DownloadManager Update the URLs for DO Job 2C86DA36-F73C-4CEA-BE77-C4A714DF3F94 - Update 96FDE0BF-DBC9-44E8-8AA0-3CB0C29FA5CE.200

2023/11/27 16:20:25.0598305 4404 1292 DownloadManager 0 of 1 files' URLs are updated.

2023/11/27 16:20:25.0601303 4404 1292 DownloadManager Download job 2C86DA36-F73C-4CEA-BE77-C4A714DF3F94 resumed.

2023/11/27 16:20:36.2263697 4404 4856 Shared Power status changed

2023/11/27 16:20:36.2264167 4404 4856 Agent Effective power state: AC; IsOnAC: Yes.

2023/11/27 16:20:36.2264217 4404 4856 Agent Effective power state: AC; IsOnAC: Yes.

2023/11/27 16:20:36.2264348 4404 4856 IdleTimer WU operation (DL.UpdateOrchestrator, operation # 450) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority

2023/11/27 16:20:36.2264406 4404 4856 Agent Released network PDC reference for callId {34EFDE9E-A731-4078-B7EE-71B77C3722D7}; ActivationID: 450

2023/11/27 16:20:36.2264499 4404 4856 IdleTimer WU operation (DL.UpdateOrchestrator) started; operation # 451; does use network; is not at background priority

2023/11/27 16:20:36.2264541 4404 4856 Agent Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {34EFDE9E-A731-4078-B7EE-71B77C3722D7} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 451.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.0503467 4404 1292 DownloadManager DO job initialized: JobId = {7463B923-E1F4-422A-B395-582913FA8F99}

2023/11/27 16:20:41.0553748 4404 1292 DownloadManager Downloading from http://10.17.x.x:8530/Content/2E/55781208AAA5FDA6EA8267082442EDFB3566E32E.exe to C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\567d85a1e3c7fb38aeb95dbaad69674a\55781208aaa5fda6ea8267082442edfb3566e32e (full file)

2023/11/27 16:20:41.0553877 4404 1292 DownloadManager Created download job 7463B923-E1F4-422A-B395-582913FA8F99; streaming data: No.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.0571606 4404 1292 DownloadManager New download job {7463B923-E1F4-422A-B395-582913FA8F99} for UpdateId C8D27018-8E1D-4AF4-AD67-EE76224214CF.200

2023/11/27 16:20:41.0575265 4404 1292 DownloadManager Update the URLs for DO Job 7463B923-E1F4-422A-B395-582913FA8F99 - Update C8D27018-8E1D-4AF4-AD67-EE76224214CF.200

2023/11/27 16:20:41.0579386 4404 1292 DownloadManager 0 of 1 files' URLs are updated.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.0585804 4404 1292 DownloadManager Download job 7463B923-E1F4-422A-B395-582913FA8F99 resumed.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.0692453 4404 1292 DownloadManager DO job initialized: JobId = {C9CCBEA9-2A3F-4DFC-95B1-2B8ED668A6B3}

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1174358 4404 1292 DownloadManager Downloading from http://10.17.x.x:8530/Content/DE/47DF58A621099F71BF22185C2E5A8D7B0011A9DE.exe to C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\a0e113f5c02fdce37db0d8aa14f74a97\47df58a621099f71bf22185c2e5a8d7b0011a9de (full file)

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1174464 4404 1292 DownloadManager Created download job C9CCBEA9-2A3F-4DFC-95B1-2B8ED668A6B3; streaming data: No.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1183717 4404 1292 DownloadManager New download job {C9CCBEA9-2A3F-4DFC-95B1-2B8ED668A6B3} for UpdateId E99F6E29-371F-40EA-9CB5-27AE26A2B78D.200

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1187120 4404 1292 DownloadManager Update the URLs for DO Job C9CCBEA9-2A3F-4DFC-95B1-2B8ED668A6B3 - Update E99F6E29-371F-40EA-9CB5-27AE26A2B78D.200

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1190936 4404 1292 DownloadManager 0 of 1 files' URLs are updated.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1194568 4404 1292 DownloadManager Download job C9CCBEA9-2A3F-4DFC-95B1-2B8ED668A6B3 resumed.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1243292 4404 4856 Shared UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 0.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1308024 4404 1292 Agent Effective power state: AC; IsOnAC: Yes.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1308107 4404 1292 IdleTimer WU operation (DL.UpdateOrchestrator, operation # 451) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1308141 4404 1292 Agent Released network PDC reference for callId {34EFDE9E-A731-4078-B7EE-71B77C3722D7}; ActivationID: 451

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1308203 4404 1292 IdleTimer WU operation (DL.UpdateOrchestrator) started; operation # 452; does use network; is not at background priority

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1308518 4404 1292 Agent Obtained a network PDC reference for callID {34EFDE9E-A731-4078-B7EE-71B77C3722D7} with No-Progress-Timeout set to 4294967295; ActivationID: 452.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1490301 4404 3644 Agent WU client calls back to download call {34EFDE9E-A731-4078-B7EE-71B77C3722D7} with code Call progress and error 0

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1522977 4404 4856 Shared UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 1.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1581912 4404 1292 DownloadManager * END * Begin Downloading Updates [CallerId = UpdateOrchestrator] [Call ID = {34EFDE9E-A731-4078-B7EE-71B77C3722D7}] [hr = 0x00000000]

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1588215 4404 1292 DownloadManager Update the URLs for DO Job 2C86DA36-F73C-4CEA-BE77-C4A714DF3F94 - Update 96FDE0BF-DBC9-44E8-8AA0-3CB0C29FA5CE.200

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1592176 4404 1292 DownloadManager 0 of 1 files' URLs are updated.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1593892 4404 1292 DownloadManager Download job 2C86DA36-F73C-4CEA-BE77-C4A714DF3F94 resumed.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1599560 4404 1292 DownloadManager Update the URLs for DO Job 7463B923-E1F4-422A-B395-582913FA8F99 - Update C8D27018-8E1D-4AF4-AD67-EE76224214CF.200

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1603139 4404 1292 DownloadManager 0 of 1 files' URLs are updated.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.1604985 4404 1292 DownloadManager Download job 7463B923-E1F4-422A-B395-582913FA8F99 resumed.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.2834543 4404 4856 Shared UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 0.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.4878064 4404 1292 DownloadManager Update the URLs for DO Job C9CCBEA9-2A3F-4DFC-95B1-2B8ED668A6B3 - Update E99F6E29-371F-40EA-9CB5-27AE26A2B78D.200

2023/11/27 16:20:41.4882546 4404 1292 DownloadManager 0 of 1 files' URLs are updated.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.4884481 4404 1292 DownloadManager Download job C9CCBEA9-2A3F-4DFC-95B1-2B8ED668A6B3 resumed.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.4889801 4404 4856 Shared UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 0.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.4923291 4404 1292 DownloadManager Received power state change notification: Old: AC; New: AC.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.4928748 4404 1292 DownloadManager Update the URLs for DO Job 2C86DA36-F73C-4CEA-BE77-C4A714DF3F94 - Update 96FDE0BF-DBC9-44E8-8AA0-3CB0C29FA5CE.200

2023/11/27 16:20:41.4932949 4404 1292 DownloadManager 0 of 1 files' URLs are updated.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.4934807 4404 1292 DownloadManager Download job 2C86DA36-F73C-4CEA-BE77-C4A714DF3F94 resumed.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.4940538 4404 1292 DownloadManager Update the URLs for DO Job 7463B923-E1F4-422A-B395-582913FA8F99 - Update C8D27018-8E1D-4AF4-AD67-EE76224214CF.200

2023/11/27 16:20:41.4950772 4404 1292 DownloadManager 0 of 1 files' URLs are updated.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.4952608 4404 1292 DownloadManager Download job 7463B923-E1F4-422A-B395-582913FA8F99 resumed.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.4958014 4404 1292 DownloadManager Update the URLs for DO Job C9CCBEA9-2A3F-4DFC-95B1-2B8ED668A6B3 - Update E99F6E29-371F-40EA-9CB5-27AE26A2B78D.200

2023/11/27 16:20:41.4961798 4404 1292 DownloadManager 0 of 1 files' URLs are updated.

2023/11/27 16:20:41.4963363 4404 1292 DownloadManager Download job C9CCBEA9-2A3F-4DFC-95B1-2B8ED668A6B3 resumed.

2023/11/27 16:33:12.2669354 4404 1292 Misc Got WSUS Client/Server URL: http://10.17.x.x:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx""

2023/11/27 16:33:12.2696437 4404 1292 WebServices Proxy Behavior set to 1 for service url http://10.17.x.x:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx

2023/11/27 16:33:12.2696889 4404 1292 ProtocolTalker OK to reuse existing configuration

2023/11/27 16:33:12.2696934 4404 1292 ProtocolTalker Existing cookie is valid, just use it

2023/11/27 16:33:12.2696953 4404 1292 ProtocolTalker PTInfo: Server requested registration

2023/11/27 16:33:12.3441152 4404 1292 Misc Got WSUS Reporting URL: http://10.17.x.x:8530/ReportingWebService/ReportingWebService.asmx""

2023/11/27 16:33:12.3458547 4404 1292 IdleTimer WU operation (CLegacyEventUploader::HandleEvents) started; operation # 453; does use network; is at background priority

2023/11/27 16:33:12.3459791 4404 1292 WebServices Auto proxy settings for this web service call.

2023/11/27 16:33:12.3777777 4404 1292 IdleTimer WU operation (CLegacyEventUploader::HandleEvents, operation # 453) stopped; does use network; is at background priority

2023/11/27 16:42:29.2694656 4404 7804 Agent FAILED [80248014] GetServiceObject couldn't find service '7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D'.

2023/11/27 16:42:29.2694681 4404 7804 Agent FAILED [80248014] Method failed [CAgentServiceManager::GetServiceObject:1902]

2023/11/27 16:42:30.4262031 4404 7804 Agent FAILED [80248014] GetServiceObject couldn't find service '7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D'.

2023/11/27 16:42:30.4262157 4404 7804 Agent FAILED [80248014] Method failed [CAgentServiceManager::GetServiceObject:1902]

2023/11/27 16:42:30.4271901 2232 10076 ComApi IUpdateServiceManager::AddService2

2023/11/27 16:42:30.4271981 2232 10076 ComApi Service ID = {7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d}

2023/11/27 16:42:30.4272006 2232 10076 ComApi Allow pending registration = Yes; Allow online registration = Yes; Register service with AU = Yes

2023/11/27 16:42:30.4279032 4404 7804 Agent FAILED [80248014] GetServiceObject couldn't find service '7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D'.

2023/11/27 16:42:30.4279054 4404 7804 Agent FAILED [80248014] Method failed [CAgentServiceManager::GetServiceObject:1902]

2023/11/27 16:42:30.4376227 4404 7804 SLS Get response for service 7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D - forceExpire[False] asyncRefreshOnExpiry[True]

2023/11/27 16:42:30.4377412 4404 7804 SLS Retrieving SLS response from server...

2023/11/27 16:42:30.4378810 4404 7804 SLS Making request with URL HTTPS://sls.update.microsoft.com/SLS/{7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D}/x64/10.0.17763.5122/0?CH=756&L=en-US&P=&PT=0x8&WUA=10.0.17763.3532&MK=Amazon+EC2&MD=m6i.large and send SLS events.

2023/11/27 16:42:51.4637130 4404 7804 Misc FAILED [80072EE2] Send request

2023/11/27 16:42:51.4637196 4404 7804 Misc FAILED [80072EE2] WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation (retrying with default proxy)

2023/11/27 16:43:12.4988126 4404 7804 Misc FAILED [80072EE2] Send request

2023/11/27 16:43:12.4988214 4404 7804 Misc FAILED [80072EE2] Library download error. Will retry. Retry Counter:0

2023/11/27 16:43:33.5545873 4404 7804 Misc FAILED [80072EE2] Send request

2023/11/27 16:43:33.5545932 4404 7804 Misc FAILED [80072EE2] WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation (retrying with default proxy)
```

Comment: There's a very long discussion about that error: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/windows-update-error-0x80240034/ef877ec1-a3d6-4a4e-a9aa-3ccdf5ff2ff7

Comment: Can you give examples of some failing updates?

Comment: KB890830 Windows Malicious Software Tool, KB 2267602 Security Intelligence for Microsoft Defender Antivirus, KB5030333 SQL Server 2019 RTM Cumulative Update, KB5029377 Security Update for SQL Server 2019 RTM GDR. Those are just a few.

Comment: We are going to need the detail Windows Update logs to troubleshoot your problem.  Please make sure you strip them down to only the relevant information. If you manually download these files, upload them to the VM, and run them as an Administrator within the VM do they install?  You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.  I will be unable to help you if you submit relevant information as a comment.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound I added the logs and answered your question there.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by adding the .exe file extension with applicaiton/octet-stream MIME type.